# How to specify that the constness of a function argument is optional?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two class need to Traverse members of some other class

```
class Reader {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void Process(const T& t) {
        Traverse(*this, t);
    }
    //... ends of recursion
};

class Writer {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void Process(T& t) {
        Traverse(*this, t);
    }
    //... ends of recursion
};
```

And I provide overloadings of function `Traverse` for every class which `Reader` and `Writer` needs to Process. For instance:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename T>
    friend void Traverse(T& t, const Foo& foo) { // for class Reader
        t.Process(foo.m1);
        t.Process(foo.m2);
    }

    template<typename T>
    friend void Traverse(T& t, Foo& foo) { // for class Writer
        t.Process(foo.m1);
        t.Process(foo.m2);
    }
private:
    int m1;
    int m2;
};
```

The above two overloadings of function `Traverse` in the `Foo` class body are almost the same. How can I make them one?

Comment: http://ideone.com/HWz2WJ

Answer (score 1):

Any non `const` value passed to a `const` parameter will be cast to `const` so you don't have to the second `Traverse()` unless you actually need to modify `foo`.

Comment: I need to modify `foo`, That's why the second class named `Writer`.

Comment: And Even if I don't modify them. `t.Process(foo.m1)` in `const Traverse` still fail to compile because `foo.m1` is already const but `t.Process` demanding a non const argument.